# SQL Server : find shared items in 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to write a query for SQL Server that is used to match friends in common. Names are in two columns in the same table. Only "accepted" friends should be returned.

Here's an example of the database information:

```
ID     Name_1     Name_2     Accepted
=====================================
1      Jimmy      John       1
2      John       Joey       1
3      Joey       Jimmy      1
4      John       Sally      1
5      Jimmy      Sally      0
```

In this example Jimmy is friends with John. The shared friend between these two (and desired result) is Joey. Sally is common to both as well, but Jimmy has not accepted her as a friend yet.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat less elegant looking, but possibly more performing solution could be:

```
DECLARE @person1 VARCHAR(50) = 'Jimmy'
DECLARE @person2 VARCHAR(50) = 'John'

SELECT  FriendsOfP1.Name as MutualFriend
FROM    ( SELECT    A.name_2 AS Name
          FROM      friends A
          WHERE     ( A.name_1 = @person1 )
                    AND Accepted = 1
                    AND name_2 <> @person2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    A.name_1
          FROM      friends A
          WHERE     ( A.name_2 = @person1 )
                    AND Accepted = 1
                    AND name_1 <> @person2 ) AS friendsOfP1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT A.name_2 AS Name
             FROM   friends A
             WHERE  ( A.name_1 = @person2 )
                    AND Accepted = 1
                    AND name_2 <> @person1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT A.name_1
             FROM   friends A
             WHERE  ( A.name_2 = @person2 )
                    AND Accepted = 1
                    AND name_1 <> @person1 ) AS FriendsOfP2
ON      FriendsOfP1.Name = FriendsOfP2.Name
```

Comment: your solution one seems perform better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try with this double self join for mutual friendship:

```
SELECT Friend_1, Friend_2, COMMON
FROM
(
SELECT f2.NAME_1 AS Friend_1
      ,f1.NAME_2 AS Friend_2
      ,f2.Name_2 AS COMMON
FROM friends f1
INNER JOIN friends f2
ON f1.NAME_1 = f2.NAME_2
WHERE f1.accepted = 1 AND f2.accepted = 1
) T
INNER JOIN FRIENDS F3
ON (F3.Name_1 = Friend_1 AND F3.Name_2 = Friend_2)
OR (F3.Name_2 = Friend_1 AND F3.Name_1 = Friend_2)
WHERE F3.ACCEPTED <> 0 AND Friend_1 = 'John' AND Friend_2 = 'Jimmy'
```

COMMON is common friend.

Related [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5d75/21)

**Note**: I'm not sure this structure is the best one to hold this kind of relation, you have rules on mutual friendship, about friendship rejection but it looks like you'd know nothing about these infos. Do you know only partial informations or is this your storage system/architecture?

Comment: This solution is nice and compact, but where do I specify the two names to find the common friend for?

Comment: @JohnVanHorn add AND clause in the external wrapping query passing the value of parameter from your code or an SQL function